# Angular + UI Router, changing title on $stateChangeSuccess (event fires too early?)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, angular-ui-router

I implemented a custom page title according to ngBoilerplate:

https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp/blob/v0.3.1-release/src/app/app.js

```
.controller( 'AppCtrl', function AppCtrl ( $scope, $location ) {
  $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    if ( angular.isDefined( toState.data.pageTitle ) ) {
      $scope.pageTitle = toState.data.pageTitle + ' | ngBoilerplate' ;
    }
  });
})
```

So basically, the title changes on each `$stateChangeSuccess` event. The problem is, that in my browser history, it saves the new title as the title of the last page. So for instance if I am at a page with the title "Home" and navigate to a page with the title "About", my history will show "About" as last item, but navigate correctly to "Home" when I click on it. I fear that this will really confuse people.

So I came up with a "hack", that seems to solve this problem:

```
.controller( 'AppCtrl', function AppCtrl ( $scope, $location ) {
  var nextTitle = "";

  $scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function (event, newUrl, oldUrl) {
    $scope.pageTitle = nextTitle;
  });

  $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    if ( angular.isDefined( toState.data.pageTitle ) ) {
      nextTitle = toState.data.pageTitle + ' | ngBoilerplate' ;
    }
  });
})
```

So now, the title will be save in a variable first and will be assigned to the scope only on `$locationChangeSuccess`. This seems to work, but I don't know how reliable this is.

So my question is, I guess, how to do this correctly. How do I get a reliable changing page title, that gets it's data from the current state?

And furthermore out of interest: Why doesn't it work with `$stateChangeSuccess`? Is there a reason why this event fires so early?

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32670723/4252741) to the more generic question of setting the page title in UI-router. The workaround is to use the `$timeout` service to run the title update asynchronously. The function will be run after the current script finishes.

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function (event, toState) {
  $timeout(function () {
    // Needed to ensure the title is changed *after* the url change
    // Ensures history entries are correct.
    $window.document.title = toState.name; 
  });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Mean.js provides a great [page-title](https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/master/modules/core/client/directives/page-title.client.directive.js) directive for that.

Answer (score -3):

Have a look at how it's done here: [UI Router Sample - index.html](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/d6b95ef23d9dacb4eba08897f5190a0bcddb3a48/sample/index.html#L34)

```
<!-- could easily use a custom property of the state here instead of 'name' -->
<title ng-bind="$state.current.name + ' - ui-router'">ui-router</title>
```

Comment: A code snippet or explanation would be useful in case the linked project gets modified or removed.