# Set Page Title with Angular and UI-Router based on data in controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm currently using the directive found in this question to change my page titles.

[Set Page title using UI-Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23813599/set-page-title-using-ui-router)

Then, in my app.js file, I append the pageTitle to data, like so:

```
.state('home', {
  url: '/home'
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
  controller: 'homeController'
  data: {
    pageTitle: 'Home'
  }
})
```

But say, for instance, if homeController had a `$scope.todaysDate` variable that was fetched from a service. Is there a way to access that variable in my router, so I can change data and pageTitle to something like:

```
data: {
  pageTitle: 'Home ' + $scope.todaysDate
}
```

I'm able to go into the controller and using `$rootScope.pageTitle = 'some value'` I can see it changes the variable to `'some value'` when I look in the Batarang console tool, but the actual page title doesn't change.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a [resolve](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve) would work in this case. If you want to make sure some data is always available to a state controller you can use a resolve. For example lets say I had a service called, "calendar" and it exposes a function called, "getTodaysDate". I could do the following:

```
.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'homeController',
    resolve:{
            pageTitle:  function(calendar){
            return 'Home ' + calendar.getTodaysDate();
        }
    }
})
```

Now "pageTitle" will be resolved and injected into "homeController" before the state change. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning resolve. It seems to be the correct approach. I haven't got it working yet. I think I'm doing something wrong with the code in my factory. (I said it was a  service earlier but it's actually a factory)

Comment: @twinb what you have IS a service. There is more than one way to register a service on a module. You are using the factory method (most common) Take a look here for details: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Comment: @twinb are you having any luck with this? I would be glad to provide you a working example if it would help. This is a pretty common use case and I think you might just be struggling with a small learning curve.

Comment: sorry for the late response. I couldn't get it working so kinda gave up on it for now. I understand how resolve works but I think I'm goofing things up in the service/factory(good point btw) with the function I was trying to call. A working example would be great if it didn't take too much of your time.