# Add reference to $state and $stateParams to $rootScope in Typescript (angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to set the page title of my angular app based on data of the current state (configured in ui-router).

```
 <title ng-bind="$state.current.data.pageTitle></title>
```

On this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23813599/set-page-title-using-ui-router), I found the following to add a reference to $state/$stateParams to the root scope:

```
.run([ '$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
    function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
        $rootScope.$state = $state;
        $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
    }])
```

How can I translate this to typescript?

```
 function run($rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService, $state : ng.ui.IState, $stateParams : ng.ui.IStateParamsService) {
    $rootScope.$state // 'state' cannot be resolved
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UPDATE: previous version of this answer would not be working with a angular strict mode, or minification.

I would therefore suggest to add this [ng-strict-di](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/strictdi) directive into *index.html*:

```
<html data-ng-app="App" ng-strict-di> // see ng-strict-di
  <head>
```

And that would reveal that the proper way is:

```
module App
{
    export class RootConfig
    {
        static inject = ['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams'];

        constructor(
            $rootScope: any, //ng.IRootScopeService,
            $state: ng.ui.IStateProvider,
            $stateParams: ng.ui.IStateParamsService)
        {
            $rootScope.$state = $state;
            $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
        }
    }
}

angular.module('App')
    // wrong - not working in minified world
    // .run(App.RootConfig);
    // correct
    .run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', App.RootConfig]);
```

*Why this `$rootScope: any, //ng.IRootScopeService,` instead of this: `$rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService,`? To make life easier... and quickly assign not declared properties `$state` and `$stateParams`*

Comment: @xvdiff have to say sorry, my answer was working half way. It is very improtant to change that as shown in my update, to avoid any issues later with minification

Comment: You can also create an interface that extends `IRootScopeService` to add `$state` and `$stateParams` e.g.
`interface ICustomRootScopeService extends ng.IRootScopeService {
        $state: ng.ui.IStateProvider;
        $stateParams: ng.ui.IStateParamsService;
}` (excuse formatting.

Answer (score 5):

I found a cleaner route than setting it to `any`

```
declare module app {
    interface IScope extends ng.IScope {
        $root:IRootScopeService
    }

    interface IRootScopeService extends ng.IRootScopeService {
        $state:ng.ui.IStateService
    }
}
```

Then to use it just declare like

```
constructor(
        $rootScope: app.IRootScopeService,
        $state: ng.ui.IStateProvider
{
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
}
```

Comment: Adding to **Marius**'s answer, I have answered a different question which will keep the `declaration` modular.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/37225633/4742733