# Typescript: Property doesn't exist on the $rootScope (Angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, service, typescript

Getting an error when adding a value to the rootscope in Typescript.

```
class TestClass{
   this.rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService;
   constructor($rootScope){
       this.rootScope = $rootScope;
    }

    addValueToRoot=()=>{
       this.rootScope.val1 = "something";    //Error: Property doesn't exist on the IRootScopeService
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That is because (as the compiler says) `val1` does not exist on `ng.IRootScopeService`. You need to extend it to adapt it to your needs, e.g.

```
interface MyRootScope extends ng.IRootScopeService {
  val1: string
}
```

Then you can just use this interface in your class:

```
class TestClass {
  this.rootScope: MyRootScope;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You are probably using TypeScript 1.6 which starts catching this kind of errors.

What I usually do is either:

1. use `$rootScope: any`
2. do `($rootscope as any).val1 = ...`
3. use `$rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService & { [name:string]: any };`

No.3 adds allowance of additional properties to the type.  You can even save it under a type name for reuse:

```
type IExpandable = { [name:string]:any };

$rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService & IExpandable;
```

Comment: Looking at option 3, how would one inject this in a controller?

Answer (score 2):

Other alternatives are:

```
this.rootScope["val1"] = "something";
(<any>(this.rootScope)).val1 = "something";
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

In a separate file, I `declare module app`:

```
// IRootScopeService.d.ts
declare module app {
    interface IRootScopeService extends ng.IRootScopeService {
        //
        $state: ng.ui.IState
        //
        previousState: any;
        currentState: any;
    }
}
```

I named this `IRootScopeService.d.ts` as it is a declaration files working with `declare` keyword.  To keep it modular, this file will be only for accessing the `interface` with `app.IRootScopeService`.

Now, within the controller file, this is how the `controller` function is:

```
//CoreCtrl-ctrl.ts
...
function CoreCtrl(
        $state: angular.ui.IState,
        $rootScope: app.IRootScopeService
    ) {
        var vm = this;

        $rootScope.previousState = undefined;
        $rootScope.currentState = undefined;
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(ev, to, toParams, from, fromParams) {
            $rootScope.previousState = from.name;
            $rootScope.currentState = to.name;
        })
        // $rootScope.previousState = undefined;
        // $rootScope.currentState = undefined;
    }
    ...
```

Note the `app.IRootScopeService` that gives us the `type` we want for `$rootScope`.  Now `$rootScope.currentState` and `$rootScope.previousState` will not give error in `typescript`.

**PART 2**

We can add more `interfaces` to module `app` in a new file `IScope.d.ts` just to keep things modular :

```
// IScope.d.ts
declare module app {
    interface IScope extends ng.IScope {
        // 
        $root: IRootScopeService;
        // 
        greet:string;
        name:string;
        address:string;
    }
}
```

Now, we have two **personalized/customized** interfaces `app.IRootScopeService` and `app.IState` where we can keep adding new `properties` we would like to add to `$rootScope` and `$scope`.

Note that we did not prefix `ng.` in `$root: IRootScopeService;` because we are accessing `app.IRootScopeService` from inside `module app`.

Hope this helps.  Good Luck.