# $rootScope property is not updating on route change in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

In my index.html `<head>` I have the following element:

```
<link
    rel="alternate"
    type="application/rss+xml"
    title="{{feedJobsTagName}} jobs feed"
    href="{{feedJobTagsUrl}}"
    ng-if="feedJobTagsUrl">
```

When I change routes to a new tag, I have a resolver that fetches the tag and updates the two properties on the root scope (`TagShowCtrl`):

```
$rootScope.feedJobTagsUrl = '/feeds/jobs/'+tag.type+'s/'+tag.nameLower;
$rootScope.feedJobsTagName = tag.name;
```

If I refresh the page, I get the correct tag name, however if I just change routes by following links to a new tag name it seems to cache the first name and not update it with the new one:

```
.when('/tags/:slug/:id', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/tags/show',
    controller: 'TagShowCtrl',
    resolve: {
        tag: ['$route', 'Tag', function($route, Tag){
            return Tag.get({ id: $route.current.params.id}).$promise;
        }]
    }
})
```

Comment: I've solved the similar issue with `<title>` tag following this advice: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26086324/3905211

Answer (score 0):

To make your changes apply to the view, you have to bind the **$routeChangeSuccess** 
event on the `$scope` of your controller.

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(next, current) {
    $rootScope.feedJobTagName = "new value";
});
```

> Please mind that it won't work correctly on `$rootScope` inside your controller.

Although your controller's scope is updated, the changes won't apply to the view, because your **route's resolve object** returns a **promise**. (See what happens exactly [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider#when))

As for all asynchronous tasks, you either need to `$apply` the changes to the digest loop or use the [events provided by Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#integration-with-the-browser-event-loop) - which is in your case `$routeChangeSuccess`.

Mind that the controller is **instantiated after** the asyncronous `get` promise has been fulfilled.