# How to create an Angular directive in the <head> section of a document?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, html-head

I am new to `angular.js`. I am trying to create a directive to add some title and meta tags in the `<head>` section of html documents, but I am having some trouble.

My `index.html` document is as following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <base href="/">
    <seo-title></seo-title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/incl/js/myApp.js"></script>
</head>
<body >
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

My javascript is:

```
var app = angular.module ('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', { templateUrl: 'routes/home.html'})
        .when('/pageA', { templateUrl: 'routes/pageA.html'})
        .when('/pageB', { templateUrl: 'routes/pageB.html'})
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true
    });

}]);

app.directive('seoTitle', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<title>{{seo.title}}</title>'
    };
});
```

When I open the inspector, the directive has been moved to the `<body>` and has not been replaced with the template:

[image]

How can I create directives in the header?

**P.S.:** A code example would be great!

Comment: Why would u need a directive to add meta tags? Just put them in from the start? And title can be set from a controller easily which can be assigned to the html tag and the head will have access to it.

Comment: Some page will have some meta tags and others won't. Besides, it is not only about title, it could be about setting a robots meta tag to noindex a page, etc...

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think HTML spec doesn't allow for custom elements, like `<seo-title>` as a child of `<head>`. Regardless, the template doesn't replace the directive element - you could use `replace: true` (but that is being deprecated), or you could just use an attribute directive instead `<title seo-title></title>`

Comment: no need for a template or custom element , just use `title` with `restrict:'E'` for the directive

Answer (score 5):

Your directive does not need to go in the `head` to set the title. Just have your directive inject `$window` and set `$window.document.title = 'your title'`.

**UPDATE** This is how you can update meta tags.

For updating meta tags I would use a Directive like this:

```
mmMetaTags.$inject = ['metaTags'];
function mmMetaTags(metaTags) {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element) {

            metaTags.metaTags.forEach(function(tag) {
                addMetaTag(tag.name, tag.content)
            });

            metaTags.subscribe(addMetaTag);

            function addMetaTag(name, content) {

                var tag = element[0].querySelector('meta[name="' + name + '"]'); 

                if (tag) {

                    tag.setAttribute('content', content);
                } else {

                    element.append('<meta name="' + name + '" content="' + content + '">');
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

directive('mmMetaTags', mmMetaTags);
```

Along with a service to set the metaTags:

```
function MetaTags() {

    // private
    this._tags = [];

    // private
    this._subscriber;

    var self = this;
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'metaTags', { get: function() {
        return self._tags;
     }});
}

MetaTags.prototype.addMetaTag = function(name, content) {
    this._tags.push({ name: name, content: content });
    this._updateSubscriber(name, content);
}

MetaTags.prototype.subscribe = function(callback) {
    if (!this.subscriber) {
        this._subscriber = callback;
    } else {
        throw new Error('Subscriber already attached. Only one subscriber may be added as there can only be one instance of <head>');
    }
}

// private
MetaTags.prototype._updateSubscriber = function(name, content) {
    this.subscriber(name, content);    
}

service('metaTags', MetaTags);
```

So in your `head` tag you would include the attribute `mm-meta-tags`. Then in your controller you would inject the `metaTags` service and call `addMetaTag` to update the tags.

Comment: I am aware of the simpler solution for titles, but as mentioned in the question comments, it is not only about title..

Comment: @JVerstry I updated my answer with an example of directive and service to set meta tags.

Answer (score 2):

You answer is here: [Set Page title using UI-Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23813599/set-page-title-using-ui-router), implemented in your code it could be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <base href="/">
    <title seo-title>doesn't work</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/incl/js/myApp.js"></script>
</head>
<body >
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and you js:

```
app.directive('seoTitle', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'a',
    template: 'works'
};
```

you just need to add a controller or some logic to set the title you want

Answer (score 2):

First things first: I was looking in the inspector and yes, somehow the title tag appears within the body. But it seems not to affect its function.

Now to the solution: At first glance it seems that only 
`replace: true` is missing in the declaration of the `seoTitle` directive.
Adding it solves the problem and the `seo-title` is replaced with `title` tag as planned, but Angular wraps the content in an additional `span` element as a new scope is created (even if the scope for `seoTag` is declared isolated `scope: {}`).

I came up with following solution:

```
app.directive('seoTitle', function() {

    function compile(elem, attrs, transclude) {

        return function ($scope) {
            transclude($scope, function (clone) {
                elem.empty();
                elem.append(clone[0].innerText);
            });
        };
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        compile: compile,
        template: '<title ng-transclude></title>',
    };

});
```

Usage:

```
<seo-title>My Title</seo-title>
```

As already mentioned, with `replace: true` you can remove the wrapping `seo-title` tag.

In order to remove the additionally created `span` element,
I provide the `compile` function with returns the `postLink` function.

I can't really explain, why I need to use the `transclude` function within the `postLink` function. 
It seems to be a quite common problem, that Angular creates an additional `span` element in this case.
With a little bit try and error I found that the easiest way to get rid of the `span`, is to `emtpy()` the element and append only the `innerText`.

Comment: no idea where this extra span comes from, never seen that before. Solution provided seems far more complex than what is needed

Answer (score 0):

You can try [metang](https://github.com/timsly/metang) library. Beside title it supports other meta tags(description, author, og:*, twitter:*, etc)

Comment: Hey can you please help me with metang by any sample

Comment: Yes, sure. Here is example https://gist.github.com/timsly/85aadbfb559d85c03a0995f58b28ba56

Answer (score 0):

```
    angular.directive('ngHead', function () {
    let strHtml = '';
    strHtml += '<meta charset="utf-8">';
    strHtml += '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">';
    strHtml += '<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">';
    strHtml += '<meta name="google" content="notranslate" />';
    strHtml += '<title>';
    strHtml += '    title';
    strHtml += '</title>';
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.append(strHtml);
        }
    }
});
```

in your html `<head ng-head></head>`
work for me.