# How to dynamically add links to canonical urls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canonical-link

I am working on a project in angular where I need to add dynamic links to [canonical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element) urls. So as the page changes the url in canonical href should also change/update.There are some conditions I have added because of which only parent Urls should be added.
Below is the code:

```
var url         = window.location.href,
    urlSegments = url.split("/").length - 1 - (url.indexOf("http://")==-1?0:2);
            if(urlSegments <= 7) {
                var link = document.createElement('link');
                link.setAttribute('rel', 'canonical');
                link.setAttribute('href', url);
                document.head.appendChild(link);
            }
```

But this is not working.What wrong am I doing here and what can be the best solution for this.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You tagged it with `angulajs` tag so I think you should do it Angular way - with directive. You haven't specified what exactly is not working so hard to give any details, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31277637/how-to-create-an-angular-directive-in-the-head-section-of-a-document) you have some example on how to manipulate `<head>` elements with a directive.