# How to change pageTitle dynamically on state change angularjs inside state routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I want to change the pageTitle inside data in state Provider.

```
$stateProvider.state(test, {
  url: '/test',
  views: {
    main: {
      controller: 'TestCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'admin/test.tpl.html'
    }
  },
  data: {
    pageTitle: 'Need some dynamic title',                        
  },                    
});
```

Here I want to set the page title dynamically may be somewhere inside `$state.go()`.

I tried using

```
//The controller from where the state is called and we got to know what the title is
$state.get('test').data.pageTitle = $scope.title;
$state.go('test');
```

But nothing has happened.
Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Page title using UI-Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23813599/set-page-title-using-ui-router)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `$state.go()` you can do:

```
$state.go('test', {pageTitle: $scope.title});
```

(or it will be `data.pageTitle: $scope.title`, I'm not absolutely sure).

And you didn't include any HTML, so don't forget to bind value to `title` tag like this:

```
<title ng-bind="$state.current.data.pageTitle"></title>
```

Comment: It will not work like this. You are using it as a parameter, it will not reflect.

Comment: What does {notify: false} do by the way?

Comment: @RamsingNadeem, `notify: false` suppresses the `$stateChange` events, in this case it doesn't required I think.

Comment: Okay; cool. When can it be used? Is it connected to {reload: true} or {reload: 'stateName'}?

Comment: @RamsingNadeem, " Is it connected to {reload: true} or {reload: 'stateName'}?" Can't say really

Comment: Oh; okay; checked out the docs. Can be used to listen to the $stateChange events. Thanks.