# AngularJS UI-Router edit page title

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm working on an AngularJs application with symfony 2.8 backoffice. I want to edit the contact page title. This is the code of the contact page :

```
<div ng-controller="contactFormCtrl">
<fieldset>
    <h1 translate="front.CONTACT">Contact</h1>
    <h2 ng-bind-html="post.content"></h2>
    <form  name="contactForm" id="contactForm" class="form" data-ng-submit="submitForm(contactForm)">
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':contactForm.firstName.$dirty && contactForm.firstName.$invalid, 'has-success':contactForm.firstName.$valid}">
            <label for="contactFirstName" class="control-label">
                <span translate="content.list.fields.FIRSTNAME">First Name</span>
                <span class="symbol required"></span>
            </label>
            <span class="input-icon">
                <input name="firstName" id="contactFirstName" ng-model="contact.firstName" type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" placeholder="[[ 'content.list.fields.FIRSTNAME' | translate ]]" ng-required="true">
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
            </span>
            <span class="error text-small block" ng-if="contactForm.firstName.$dirty && contactForm.firstName.$error.required" translate="content.form.messages.FIRSTNAMEREQUIRED">FirstName is required.</span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':contactForm.lastName.$dirty && contactForm.lastName.$invalid, 'has-success':contactForm.lastName.$valid}">
            <label for="contactLastName" class="control-label">
                <span translate="content.list.fields.LASTNAME">Last Name</span>
                <span class="symbol required"></span>
            </label>
            <span class="input-icon">
                <input name="lastName" id="contactLastName" ng-model="contact.lastName" type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" placeholder="[[ 'content.list.fields.LASTNAME' | translate ]]" ng-required="true">
                <i class="fa fa-user-o"></i>
            </span>
            <span class="error text-small block" ng-if="contactForm.lastName.$dirty && contactForm.lastName.$error.required" translate="content.form.messages.LASTNAMEREQUIRED">LastName is required.</span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':contactForm.contactEmail.$dirty && contactForm.contactEmail.$invalid, 'has-success':contactForm.contactEmail.$valid}">
            <label for="contactEmail" class="control-label">
                <span translate="content.list.fields.EMAIL">Email</span>
                <span class="symbol required"></span>
            </label>
            <span class="input-icon">
                <input name="contactEmail" id="contactEmail" ng-model="contact.email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="[[ 'content.list.fields.EMAIL' | translate ]]" ng-required="true">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
            </span>
            <span class="error text-small block" ng-if="contactForm.contactEmail.$dirty && contactForm.contactEmail.$error.required" translate="content.form.messages.EMAILREQUIRED">Email is required.</span>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':contactForm.contactSubject.$dirty && contactForm.contactSubject.$invalid, 'has-success':contactForm.contactSubject.$valid}">
            <label for="contactSubject" class="control-label">
                <span translate="content.list.fields.SUBJECT">Subject</span>
                <span class="symbol required"></span>
            </label>
            <span class="input-icon">
                <input name="contactSubject" id= "contactSubject" ng-model="contact.subject" type="text" class="form-control" name="contactSubject" placeholder="[[ 'content.list.fields.SUBJECT' | translate ]]" ng-required="true">
                <i class="ti-marker-alt"></i>
            </span>
            <span class="error text-small block" ng-if="contactForm.contactSubject.$dirty && contactForm.contactSubject.$error.required" translate="content.form.messages.SUBJECTREQUIRED">Subject is required.</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':contactForm.contactMessage.$dirty && contactForm.contactMessage.$invalid, 'has-success':contactForm.contactMessage.$valid}">
            <label for="contactMessage" class="control-label">
                <span translate="content.list.fields.MESSAGE">Message</span>
                <span class="symbol required"></span>
            </label>
            <span class="input-icon">
                <textarea name="contactMessage" id="contactMessage" ng-model="contact.message" rows="10" class="form-control" name="contactMessage" placeholder="[[ 'content.list.fields.MESSAGE' | translate ]]" ng-required="true"></textarea>
                <i class="fa fa-message-o"></i>
            </span>
            <span class="error text-small block" ng-if="contactForm.contactMessage.$dirty && contactForm.contactMessage.$error.required" translate="content.form.messages.CONTACTMESSAGEREQUIRED">Message is required.</span>
        </div>

    <button type="button" ng-click="submitForm(contactForm)" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-disabled="disableSubmit"> <!--  ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid" -->
        <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" ng-if="disableSubmit"></i><i class="fa fa-envelope" ng-if="!disableSubmit"></i> <span translate="content.common.SEND">Send</span>
    </button>
</form>
```

when i use the inspector i find this function :

```
<title ng-bind="pageTitle()" class="ng-binding">E-electricity</title>
```

A function called pageTitle() to automatically generate a title for each page. i want to edit E-electricity to E-electricity-contact.

Comment: chech the controller where you have defined `pageTitle()` and then write logic to generate what you expect

Comment: I find more than 15 calls of this function in a different js files so how can i fixed it  ?

Comment: This post may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23813599/set-page-title-using-ui-router

Comment: that helps a lot thanks